# Problems installing .NET 3.5 Client Profile

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I have some scenarios I want to test, but I cannot seem to get my machine (Windows 8.1) to uninstall versions of .NET.

I am able to turn off .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.5 in the Windows Features box. No .NET frameworks are listed in my Programs and Features box. When installing .NET 3.5 Client Profile a message stops me saying I already have higher versions of .NET installed.

I don't know where else to look. Any ideas? Do I need to try a different OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile is only valid for Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, or below.

Windows 7 and onward include the .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.x as an operating system component instead. They don't support the client profile, only the full framework for 3.5 in this case.

The [system requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5007) for the 3.5 Client Profile are:

> Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows XP